# Can't send image attachment with Gmail from my application

Tags: android, android-intent

For some reason Gmail even though it shows the PNG attachment in it's compose screen the attachment is never sent.  Not obvious to me what I am doing wrong here.

```
        view.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
        Bitmap b = view.getDrawingCache();
        try {
            boolean r = b.compress(CompressFormat.PNG, 95, new FileOutputStream(outputFile));
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        final Intent emailIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        emailIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        emailIntent.setType("image/png");
        emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[]{emailTo});
        emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, subject);
        emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, emailText);
        Uri u = Uri.fromFile(outputFile);
        emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, u);
        this.startActivityForResult(emailIntent, 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
    final Intent emailIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    emailIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    emailIntent.setType("image/png");
    emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[]{emailTo});
    emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, subject);
    emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, emailText);
    emailIntent.putExtra(Uri.fromFile(outputFile);
    emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, u);
    this.startActivityForResult(emailIntent, 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

Duh.  In onActivityResult I deleted the file.  Can't do that if Gmail is going to send it.  Would like to know if there is a way to delete it other than waiting some period of time and just whacking it.

Answer (score 0):

Put your file in `Context.getCacheDir()` directory.

Now, before you create the new file, check existing files and delete them if they are older than few hours or whatever.